# How to bind function for each element in ListView in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've rewrite a component from createClass to class definition to fit eslint-react-native linting, then I found I cannot bind function to element in Array as it used to. The former code looks like this:

```
createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <ListView style={styles.listView}
        dataSource={this.state.data}
        renderRow={this._renderTopic}
      />
    )
  },
  _renderTopic(topic) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onDelayColor="#dddddd"
        onPress={() => this._jumpTo(topic.id) }
      >
    )
  },
  _jumpTo(id) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name: 'Topic page',
      component: Topic,
      passProps: {
       topicId: id,
      },
    });
  }
})
```

When I change it to class definition:

```
{
  render() {
    return (
      <ListView style={styles.listView}
        dataSource={this.state.data}
        renderRow={this._renderTopic}
      />
    )
  }
  _renderTopic(topic) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onDelayColor="#dddddd"
        onPress={() => this._jumpTo(topic.id) }
      >
    )
  }
  _jumpTo(id) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name: 'Topic page',
      component: Topic,
      passProps: {
       topicId: id,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

It does not work again. And give an error while press the Touchable: `this2._jumpTo is not a function`

So I changed it again:

```
{
  render() {
    return (
      <ListView style={styles.listView}
        dataSource={this.state.data}
        renderRow={this._renderTopic}
      />
    )
  }
  _renderTopic(topic) {
    const nav = this.props.navigator
    let jumpTo = function(id) {
      nav.push({
        name: 'Topic page',
        component: Topic,
        passProps: {
         topicId: topic.id,
        },
      });
    };
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onDelayColor="#dddddd"
        onPress={jumpTo}
      >
    )
  }
}
```

This would through error immediately: `possible unhandled promise rejection cannot read property _currentElement of null`. (Which is strange here, the jumpTo function should be lazy, right?)

So what's the right way to bind an dynamic function to item in ListView?

Comment: Are you willing to use ES6? It would make this question trivial

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes, I'm writing ES6, using Babel-eslint and eslint to lint my code. Source code is here: https://github.com/kxxoling/PythonChina.app  Linted code is not commited yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think whitep4nther was heading in the right direction, I do the following to get around the binding in the render method

```

```
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this._renderTopic = this._renderTopic.bind(this);
  }
}
```

```

Check out this link from the docs https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding

Comment: I have several renderXX and fetchXX methods here, so I have to bind them multi times. Any good ideas to fix this?

Comment: You should look at using something like lodash,  It has a `_.bindAll` function
https://lodash.com/docs#bindAll

Comment: This helps!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With second example, wild guess ?

```
renderRow={this._renderTopic.bind(this)}
```

Comment: Not tested, but using bind is not suggested based on eslint-react plugin. https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md Even this works, I'd rather a better solution.

Comment: He's talking about your problem right after : https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#es6-classes. He suggests binding the method in the constructor, which is essentially the same without the need to create a new function in each render.

Comment: But to be fair, you don't need this kind of optimizations till some point

Comment: And there is no need to have a "better" solution, this method was specifically created to solve theses kind of problem

Comment: Your solution works, but I don't understand why I need to bind this now? On the other hand, if I can avoid using `bind()` would be better.

Comment: The answer is in the link you posted earlier, at the bottom in the page ! ;) "Unfortunately React ES6 classes do not autobind their methods like components created with the older React.createClass"

Comment: Um, maybe I need a closer look at ES class now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind this to the method

```
<ListView
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   renderRow={this._renderTopic.bind(this)}
/>
```

and add the _renderTopic method in constructor :

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this._renderTopic = this._renderTopic.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bind this if you use the react class constructor and then use arrow functions.

This is possible because arrow functions don't create a closure like functions do.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: "Some content"
    };
  }
  clickHandler = event => {
    //handle the click
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Some Content </p>
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler}> Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```